How can I create non-planar cross-sections without using CPU-intensive Booleans?
I have a complex scene with many objects and would like to make non-planar cross sections of the entire scene. With simpler scenes I'd use Booleans to cut the geometry, but in this case I don't for the following reasons:

Booleans are CPU intensive
There are hundreds (eventually to be 1000+) of objects in my scene
I want to dynamically change the cross section in the viewport and see the effect with minimal lag.

I found a neat shader node trick that references an empty (called "Cutter Control" in my example) to make shader output to one side of it transparent. All I have to do is add the following custom node group shown below to the shader output of each material that I want included in this effect.


The nice thing about this method is that it is very quick, and I can translate and rotate the empty to slice the scene any way I want, as long as all the materials I'm using have this custom "Cross Section" node. Processing time is near-instant. Below is a side-by-side example with the empty out of the range of influence on the left, and the empty moved about halfway up the z-axis on the right.

And here's a video to show how responsive this method is. This is real-time in the viewport: https://youtu.be/3WLVerEv_rc
The problem is that this method is only limited to making a planar cross section.
My question: Is there a way to create non-planar cross sections without using Booleans using this or a similar method? My imagined solution would be to use a mesh object of any shape to define a volume within which all shaders go transparent.
Credit to this YouTuber for the idea: https://youtu.be/v6YCUGTvcQ0?si=-8lLhYMVcYP6hIuU&t=46

You will have to decide which kind of section you want and use the respective mathematical formula there in the cross section node.

Thanks for that suggestion Daniel. But I was hoping to achieve something more like this, where I could create the cutaway shape I want as a mesh object and have everything within go transparent. I'm not sure there's a way to do that easily with math formulas. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture?file=Enterprise_NCC-1701-refit_cutaway_poster.jpg

Daniel, thanks again. You put me on the path of finding out more about math nodes and how they can be used to create all kinds of shapes in the shader editor. This is the video that is helping me along: https://youtu.be/oawTbgGtQ5o?si=ntqGAe3OJ_aG8OWx.  With this, I can create a cube volume, wedge volume, etc. Not quite what I was hoping to end up with, but certainly much better than what I started with.
